# XQuery find two largest values

Tags: max, xquery

I have four values that will be ever changing. I want to get a string out of them containing the two largest of those values (`"v1, v2"`). They can be in a sequence or on their own. I don't care. I have tried multiple different ways but I am no expert in this stuff and I just can't figure it out. I figured out how to get the max value in a sequence using the `max()` function but I need the second largest as well.

Comment: This question would be greatly improved if you showed what your data looks like. Is it a raw sequence? A series of elements you're retrieving the values from? Something else?

Comment: Anyhow -- think about it for a minute. You want the max, which you already know how to do, then you want *the largest value that isn't the max*.

Comment: What do you want to do if your sequence looks like `1,2,4,4`? Return `4` twice, or `2` and `4` separately?

Comment: I basically have four values ($hplayer/stats/@treb, $hplayer/stats/@ast, $hplayer/stats/@blk, and $hplayer/stats/@stl). I want to find the largest two. I can put them in a sequence if that is easier. I really don't care how (in terms of data types) they start or end. I can figure out how to finally implement it into my data, I am just looking for the couple lines that will take data in and give me the two largest int's from it. Sorry, I just don't think me giving you my code is going to really help you at all. It is very simple code and this just one piece I want to add. Thanks.

Comment: If I don't see your data, I can't test my code against it, so I can't be sure my answer will work for you. I understand and appreciate not wanting to add irrelevancies -- pruning code and data to the minimum relevant portion is an art, and something it's strongly preferred that people do when asking questions here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and http://sscce.org/

Comment: ...anyhow, if you don't make your question detailed enough that people can test their own answers, then the onus is on you to give fast and detailed responses to answers proposed. Please do so. :)

Comment: I've been playing with the idea of doing something along the lines of putting the values into a sequence. Find the 'max()' of that sequence for my first largest number. Then taking that same sequence, removing ('remove()') that first max number and then finding the 'max()' of the remaining sequence.

Comment: ...which is basically what my first answer does, albeit a bit more tersely. You've looked at it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is almost right, except inasmuch as it doesn't deal with cases where the maximum value is duplicated (and thus should be returned for both values).

```
declare variable $seq := (2,4,3,1);  (: define the input sequence :)
max($seq), max($seq[. != max($seq)]) (: evaluate to maximum and max of values not equal
                                        to the global maximum :)
```

If you wanted to handle the other case as well, one way would be thus:

```
(: from  http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_sort-as-numeric.html :)
declare function local:sort-as-numeric
  ( $seq as item()* )  as item()* {

   for $item in $seq
   order by number($item)
   return $item
};

(: define the input sequence :)
declare variable $seq := (2,4,3,1);

(: sort the sequence, then take the last and second-to-last values :)
local:sort-as-numeric($seq)[position()=(last()-1, last())]
```

...obviously, if you want a non-numeric sort, change the `order by number($item)` to `order by $item`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks Charles! Just need 'max($seq[. != max($seq)])'. Works great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic way to to get the max N from a sequence.

```
declare function local:max-N(
  $seq as item()*,
  $N as xs:int
) as item()*
{
  if ($N gt 0) 
  then 
    let $max := max($seq)[1]  
    return ($max, local:max-N($seq[. ne $max], $N - 1))
  else ()
};
```

For example, to solve the problem you describe:

```
local:max-N(
  (111, 22, 333, 4, 55, 66, 7, 88),
  2)
=> (333, 111)
```